# Resolving troubles with line breaking in paragraph

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I am working on a larger project with text I cannot alter at all, so I obviously run into various troubles with overfull and underfull hboxes &c. Therefore I've created the following macro (using of which supposes of course that hyphenation &c. is all set up already), that should work both in plain TeX and LaTeX (as it is pretty primitive):

```
\def\emergency #1 #2\par{%
\begingroup
    \ifcase #1
        \message{Emergency level 0 does nothing at all.}%
    \or
        \tolerance = 250
        \message{Emergency level 1: increasing \string\tolerance\space to \the\tolerance.}%
    \or
        \tolerance = 300
        \message{Emergency level 2: increasing \string\tolerance\space to \the\tolerance.}%
    \or
        \tolerance = 300
        \righthyphenmin = 2
        \message{Emergency level 3: increasing \string\tolerance\space to \the\tolerance,
                 decreasing \string\righthyphenmin\space to \the\righthyphenmin.}%
        \message{You might need to set hyphenation properly for this emergency level to work.}%
    \or
        \righthyphenmin = 2
        \emergencystretch = 5pt
        \message{Emergency level 4: increasing \string\emergencystretch\space to \the\emergencystretch,
                 decreasing \string\righthyphenmin\space to \the\righthyphenmin.}%
        \message{You might need to set hyphenation properly for this emergency level to work.}%
    \or
        \righthyphenmin = 2
        \emergencystretch = 8pt
        \message{Emergency level 5: increasing \string\emergencystretch\space to \the\emergencystretch,
                 decreasing \string\righthyphenmin\space to \the\righthyphenmin.}%
        \message{You might need to set hyphenation properly for this emergency level to work.}%
    \else
        \errmessage{Emergency level #1 not supported!}%
    \fi
    #2
    \par
\endgroup
}
```

The idea is to put it at the beginning of some troublesome paragraph and try levels from 1 up to 5, like this:

```
...some text of previous paragraph.

\emergency 1 % or 2 or ... or 5
Some naughty paragraph that wouldn't break nicely...
```

I am not much experienced with this kind of settings but I shall of course experiment with it and tune it. However I am under some time pressure and so I'd really appreciate if someone more experienced would perhaps look at it and hint me on whether these levels are spaced evenly enough or perhaps some are too rough, or whether some better approach should be tried or finer step inserted or so.

Thx!

Comment: probably the values are OK but I wonder if it is the best approach, if you have a bad paragraph already typeset and see `fooooobaaaar` not breaking well, rather than try to guess some integer number at the start of the paragraph that will re-jig the entire paragraph to avoid the bad break, it's rather more direct just to add some `\-` so `foo\-oo\-o\-baa\-aar`  and see what happens rather than just reducing righthyphenmin and hoping for a fortuitous extra breakpoint being generated in that case.

Comment: @david-carlisle Yes, but as I've mentioned in the post, using the macro supposes that hyphenation is already set up.

Comment: then why change \righthyphenmin in the trials if not to change hyphenation points? In what way are you getting bad paragraph breaks if not due to unbreakable words that adding hyphenation points would change?

Comment: @David: Sorry, I should have paid more attention: with `foo\-oo\-o\-baa\-aar` you obviously meant to put hyphenation points directly into the text. However, I am usually trying to avoid that as long as I can, and add a word into `\hyphenation` list instead. And here, even if I mark hyphenation point two chars before the word's end, it won't work with default `\righthyphenmin = 3`. So to enable this hyphenation point I need to change the value locally to 2.

Comment: As I say I think it's the wrong approach. You have one bad word so to try to add a non standard hyphen near the end of the word you reduce righthyphenmin and so potentially get bad hyphenation anywhere in the paragraph. Far better to add `\-` at the point where you want the hyphenation to happen.